# mediaEnded event doesn't always fire

Tags: c#, events, media-player, wav

I am using a design for playing wav files one after another. This design is based on mediaEnded event and works fine. When trying to imply this design on very short wav files, the mediaEnded event isn't always raised.
Is their a solution for this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: I find this is an intermittent problem on video as well.  Making calls to the MediaElement.Position property shows a position well past the NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds value.  Anyone know how to raise a bug report with MS ?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a workaround using a timer to periodically check for two situations:

1. Video Playback Position has not moved since last check - indicates the video is stuck.
2. Video Playback Position is beyond the end of the video - indicates the video is playing but usually just a black screen will be displayed.

If either condition exists force the next vide to start playing.

Note that this is an extract of code from a class file.

```
namespace XXXX
{
    public partial class VideoWindow :  Window
    {

        private DispatcherTimer mediaPositionTimer;  // We check the play position of the video each time this fires to see if it has hung
        double _lastPosition = -1;
        int _video_count;
        int videoDuration;  
        DateTime lastVideoStartTime;

        public VideoWindow()
        {
            adMediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;

            adMediaElement.MediaEnded  += adMediaElement_MediaEnded;
            adMediaElement.MediaOpened += adMediaElement_MediaOpened;
            adMediaElement.MediaFailed += adMediaElement_MediaFailed;

        }

        // Increment the counter every time we open a video
        void adMediaElement_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log("Media opened");
            _video_count++;
        }

        // If we have a failure then just start the next video
        void adMediaElement_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Log("Media failed");
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
            {
                PlayNextMedia();
            }));
        }

        // When a video ends start the next one
        private void adMediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Log("MediaEnded called");
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
            {
                PlayNextMedia();
            }));
        }

        // Stops and Closes any existing video
        // Increments the file pointer index
        // Switches to display ads if no more videos
        // else
        // Starts the video playing
        private void PlayNextMedia()
        {
           // Log(String.Format("PlayNextMedia called"));

            //Close the existing file and stop the timer
            EndVideo2();
            adMediaElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    adMediaElement.Stop();
                    adMediaElement.Close();
                }));

            currentMediaFileIndex++;

            if (currentMediaFileIndex > (mediaFileCount - 1))
            {
                Log(String.Format("  switching to Ads, currentMediaFileIndex = {0}", currentMediaFileIndex));
                // Now setup and then run static adds for 10 minutes
                currentMediaFileIndex = 0;
                StartAds();

            }
            else
            {
                Log(String.Format("  switching media, index = {0}", currentMediaFileIndex));
                adMediaElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    StartVideo2();
                }));
            }
        }

        // Stops the mediaPositionTimer, must be called in conjunction with a admediaElement.Pause() or Stop()
        private void EndVideo2()
        {
           // Log("EndVideo2() called");
            _is_playing = false;
            // Stop the timer
            if (mediaPositionTimer != null)
            {
                mediaPositionTimer.Stop();
            }
        }

        // Load the media file
        // Set the volume
        // Set the lastVideoStartTime variable
        private void StartVideo2()
        {
           // Log("StartVideo2() called");
            loadMediaFile(currentMediaFileIndex);

            adMediaElement.Volume = Properties.StationSettings.Default.VolumeMedia;
            lastVideoStartTime = DateTime.Now;  // Record the time we started

            // Stop the timer if it exists, otherwise create a new one
            if (mediaPositionTimer == null)
            {
                mediaPositionTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
                // Set up the timer     
                mediaPositionTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                mediaPositionTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(positionTimerTick);
            }
            else
            {
                mediaPositionTimer.Stop();
            }
            // Start it running
            adMediaElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    mediaPositionTimer.Start();
                    _is_playing = true;
                    adMediaElement.Play();
                }));
        }


        private void RestartVideo2()
        {
            //Log("Restart the video");
            adMediaElement.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate()
                {
                    mediaPositionTimer.Start();
                    _is_playing = true;
                    adMediaElement.Play();
                }));
        }

        // Check the playback position of the mediaElement has moved since the last check, 
        //  if not then the video has hung
        // Also check if the playback position exceeds the video duration,
        //  if so it has also hung
        // If video has hung then force the next one to start and report a Warning
        private void positionTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double duration;
            double currentPosition = adMediaElement.Position.TotalSeconds;

            if (adMediaElement.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
            {
                duration = adMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            }
            else
            {
                duration = 5 * 60; // Default to 5 minutes if video does not report a duration
            }

            if ((currentPosition == lastPosition) || currentPosition > (duration + 30))
            {
                // do something
                //Log("*** Video position has exceed the end of the media or video playback position has not moved ***");

                if (_is_playing)
                {
                    String logString = String.Format("*** Video {0} has frozen ({1}c:{2}l:{3}d)so forcing the next one to start ***", mediaFiles[currentMediaFileIndex], currentPosition, lastPosition, duration);
                    Log(logString);

                    PlayNextMedia();

                    // Send a message indicating we had to do this
                    mainWindow.SendHeartbeat(MainWindow.STATUS_WARNING, logString);

                }
            }
            lastPosition = currentPosition;
        }

    }
}
```